# Coq: Proving relation between < and ≤

Tags: coq, proof, coq-tactic

I am learning Coq right now and in a larger proof I have become stumped by the following sub-proof:

```
  Theorem sub : ∀ n m : nat, n ≤ m → n ≠ m → n < m.
```

Or, once unfolded:

```
  Theorem sub : ∀ n m : nat, n ≤ m → n ≠ m → S n ≤ m.
```

Here, "n ≤ m" is inductively defined as follows:

```
  Inductive le : nat → nat → Prop :=
  | le_n : ∀ n : nat, le n n
  | le_S : ∀ n m : nat, (le n m) → (le n (S m)).
```

I have not gotten very far, but my attempt looks like this:

```
  Theorem sub : ∀ n m : nat, n ≤ m → n ≠ m → n < m.
  Proof.
    unfold lt.
    intro n.
    induction n.
    - induction m.
      + intros. exfalso. contradiction.
      + admit.
    - admit.
  Admitted.
```

In the first inductive step (marked by the first admit), the inductive hypothesis shows the following :

```
1 subgoal
m : nat
IHm : 0 ≤ m → 0 ≠ m → 1 ≤ m
______________________________________(1/1)
0 ≤ S m → 0 ≠ S m → 1 ≤ S m
```

I am not sure how I can leverage this hypothesis to prove the subgoal. I would appreciate any guidance in the right direction.

Comment: In addition to @SCappella’s answer, note that just `intros; lia.` will solve it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `le` is defined as an inductive predicate, it makes more sense to do the induction on that, rather than `n`. `le` doesn't make any references to `0` or even `S n` (it does have `S m`), so induction on `n` is probably not the way to go. Induction on `m` *might* work, but it's probably harder than necessary.

Before starting a formal proof, it can often be helpful to think about how you would prove this informally (still using the same definitions, though). If you assume that `n ≤ m`, then by the inductive definition of `lt`, this means that either `n` and `m` are the same, or `m` is the successor of some number `m'` and `n` is less than or equal to `m'` (can you see why the definition of `lt` implies this?). In the first case, we'll have to use the additional hypothesis that `n ≠ m` to derive a contradiction. In the second case, we won't even need that. `n ≤ m'` implies that `S n ≤ S m'`, so since `m = S m'`, `S n ≤ m`, i.e., `n < m`.

For the formalization, we'll have to prove that assumption on the last line that `n ≤ m` implies `S n ≤ S m`. You should try a similar informal analysis to prove it. Other than that, the informal proof should be straightforward to formalize. Case analysis on `H: n ≤ m` is just `destruct H.`.

---

One more thing. This isn't essential, but can often help in the long run. When defining an inductive type (or predicate), if you can factor out a parameter that's used the same way in each constructor, it can make the induction principle more powerful. The way you have it with `le`, `n` is universally quantified and used the same way for both constructors. Every instance of `le` starts with `le n`.

```
  Inductive le : nat → nat → Prop :=
  | le_n : ∀ n : nat, le n n
  | le_S : ∀ n m : nat, (le n m) → (le n (S m)).
```

That means that we can factor out that index into a parameter.

```
  Inductive le' (n: nat) : nat → Prop :=
  | le_n' : le' n n
  | le_S' : ∀ m : nat, (le' n m) → (le' n (S m)).
```

This gives you a slightly simpler/better induction principle.

```
le'_ind
     : forall (n : nat) (P : nat -> Prop),
       P n ->
       (forall m : nat, le' n m -> P m -> P (S m)) ->
       forall n0 : nat, le' n n0 -> P n0
```

Compare this to `le_ind`.

```
le_ind
     : forall P : nat -> nat -> Prop,
       (forall n : nat, P n n) ->
       (forall n m : nat, le n m -> P n m -> P n (S m)) ->
       forall n n0 : nat, le n n0 -> P n n0
```

Basically what's happening here is that with `le_ind`, you have to prove everything for every `n`. With `le'_ind`, you only need to prove it for the particular `n` that you're using. This can sometimes simplify proofs, though it's not necessary for the proof of your theorem. It's a good exercise to prove that these two predicates are equivalent.